# the ifs aren't working properly most of the time in this code. [java]

Tags: java, if-statement, decimal

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double A=0, J=1;
        int aux=0;
        
        for(int i = 0; ; i++){
            if(A%1==0.0 && J%1==0.0) { System.out.printf("I=%.0f J=%.0f\n", A, J); }
            else if(A%1!=0 && J%1==0) { System.out.printf("I=%.1f J=%.0f\n", A, J); }
            else if(A%1==0 && J%1!=0) { System.out.printf("I=%.0f J=%.1f\n", A, J); }
            else if(A%1!=0 && J%1!=0) { System.out.printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", A, J); }
            J++;
            aux++;
            if(A==2 && aux==3) { break;}
            if(aux==3){ A+=0.2; J+=0.2; J-=3; aux=0;}
        }
}
}
```

This should print :

```
I=0 J=1
I=0 J=2
I=0 J=3
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
... 
I=2 J=5
```

first of all the code doesn't stop, as it's not reading the `if(A==2 && aux==3) { break;}`, then there's also the fact that it's not reading the first if properly either, as when I= integer and J=integer, the code should print exemple :  `I=2 J=5` but instead prints `I=2.0 J=5.0` in most cases, other than in `I=5.0 J=6, I=5.0 J=7, and I=5.0 J=8` where J is correctly being printed as an integer for some reason...

Comment: Why do you expect that the code should stop?

Comment: And what steps have you taken to try to debug the issue? Please describe these steps and the results found.

Comment: This looks to me like a floating point error.  Adding `0.2` ten times isn't going to get you to exactly `2.0`.  Perhaps you want to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`, or perhaps you'd like to use a slightly looser condition than `A == 2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a key problem here. It's not 'in java, `if` does not work'. Of course it does. It's a tool used by millions, and you're a beginner - anytime you think 'The tool must be broken', trust the millions. It isn't.

The problem you're running into is that `double` math doesn't do what you think it does.

> ```java
>  double A=0, J=1;
> .... A == 1.0 ....
> ```

Stop. You lost the game. You can't use `==` with doubles unless you really, really, really know what you are doing.

`double` does not work that way. doubles are imprecise. Computers are finite constructs. Quick, grab me a piece of paper and write out 1 divided by 3, in decimal, exactly.

Of course, you can't. 0.333333 - it never ends. Computers like binary instead of decimal, and they'd be very slow indeed if they had to emulate decimal (after all, 10 is not a power of 2, so it's not so easy to emulate base-10 math, considering!) - so, `double` does two things:

- Because computers aren't infinite, just like your piece of paper isn't, doubles **silently** lop off anything beyond 52 digits (counting both before and after the comma). It's as if you wrote 0.3333 (52 threes), and then handed it back to me and went: Here you go! - you might think that is annoying, but consider how else it should work.
- ... and because computers like binary, that's 52 **binary** digits. zeroes and ones, only.

Here's the thing: If I ask you to write 1/5th on a piece of paper, you can do that. 0.2. There. Exact perfection. That's because 1/5th is easy to 'do' in base-10 math. But in base-2 math **it is as impossible as 1/3rd is!** - a computer **CANNOT** perfectly represent 0.2 and has to round it.

Imagine I asked you to write that note for 1/3, and then I ask you to write 2 more notes, also with 1/3. You hand me back a note with 0.(52 threes) three times. I then give you those notes right back and ask you to 'please add these numbers up'.

Guess what?

**You will mess it up**. Because you will give me 0.(52 nines). Because that is indeed the correct sum of all the 3 notes you handed me. So, in this 'write it on a note' system (which is, exactly, what computers do, of course), `1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3` results in **a broken result**.

**This is part of the `double` spec - this is really how it works**.

As a consequence, doubles have errors, and given that they have errors, you need to think about any `double` value as merely 'near' what the actual number is you wanted. Once you get real good at this you'll know exactly how 'far' near can get (if you do a lot of math at very large magnitude, or do loads of ops, that error gets quite large. But, even if you don't, there's some error, even if only a very small one). Point is, given that the number is merely 'near' what you think it is, `==` **is broken** with doubles. It just doesn't work. That explains for example why `A == 2` is never `true`. For the same reason first writing down 1/3 three times lopping off any digits after the 52nd one, then adding *those* up, isn't fully 1.0 either.

Because of this, you have the wrong idea about which of the `if`s is being triggered. You get straight integers when an `if` triggers that uses `%.0f` format, and you get the `5.0` style prints when a `%.1f` is being triggered.

`%.1f` does what you ask it to: it rounds. So, if your actual number is 0.999999999 (because of that rounding issue), and you toss that at `printf("%.1f")` it dutifully prints 1.0, because 1.0 is indeed the closest number to 0.99999999 that you can print with only one digit after the comma.

#### So how do I fix this?

There are various strategies; your code is not clear about what it is actually trying to *do*, so I can't advise you on what the right answer is here. But there is a right answer to all scenarios. A small selection of common solutions:

### int/long instead

Many systems have a universally agreed upon unit of atomicity. Trying to operate sub-atomic is problematic and doesn't integrate. For example, for euros, the atomic unit is **cents**. You can ask a bank to transfer 1 cent. You cannot ask a bank to transfer half of a cent.

In such systems its generally a smarter plan to store the atomic unit and not the de facto unit. So, store cents, not euros. If you have a class representing an item stocked in a store and you need to track price, do NOT do `double price = 1.23;` for something costing 1 dollar and 23 cents. Instead fo `int price = 123;`.

### BigDecimal

BD emulates decimal math to whatever precision you want (with the one and only limitation your system's memory). It can perfectly do the math you are trying to do. But note that it comes with a bevy of caveats - it's slow as molasses and hard to use. Also, you still don't solve the division problem. Just like you can't write the exact result of 1 divided by 3 on a piece of paper, if you ask BD to divide 1 by 3 it will throw an exception instead; you have to tell it how to deal with the rounding that it has to do, and once you do that, rounding is back in and we're stick with that 'actually all doubles are more like a nebulous cloud that is merely near what it really should be' thing.

### delta

Instead of using `==`, instead you want to know if the result is merely NEAR what you are looking for. So, instead of `A == 1.0`, you'd do: `Math.abs(A - 1.0) < 0.00001` which checks if A is really really close to 1.0.